# how properly check page title?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, title

I use Selenium WebDriver in Eclipse.

I write method to check if title is displayed correctly. Here is the code:

```
class Check {
    String text_to_found;
    String reason;

    Check (String t, String r) {
        text_to_found=t;
        reason=r;
    }

    public void check_title() {
        try {
            Assert.assertTrue("Title " + text_to_found + " not found", text_to_found.equals(reason));
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            System.err.println("title not found: " + e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

I call it with such command:

```
Check title1 = new Check ("Title", driver.getTitle());
title1.check_title();
```

First time it works correct. But second (and so on) times, if I call this method (for new opened windows) it says that title is not found, but I know that it is correct. Advise, what is wrong with code?

Answer (score 0):

I just used your code to check the title of google.com. In your code if the title does not match -

```
  Check title1 = new Check ("G3oogle", driver.getTitle());
  title1.check_title();
```

We get the result  - `title not found: Title G3oogle not found`

But if it matches as below -

```
Check title1 = new Check ("Google", driver.getTitle());
  title1.check_title();
```

You are not printing anything on the console. So if you want print anything to the console  if title matches then you can modify your code -

```
     public void check_title() {    

     if(text_to_found.equals(reason)){
          System.out.println("title found: Title "+text_to_found+" found");
     }
     else{

         System.out.println("title not found: Title "+text_to_found+" not found");
     }
    }
```